# Are different subpasses able to render into render target of different mip maps?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I want to use render target of previous subpass as input of next pass.

The workflow is like the below screenshot:
[image]

I prepare a texture with four mipmaps in advance, which only mip level 0 contains valid data. I create a frame buffer of four attachmens, each attachment corresponds to one miplevel of the texture.

For first subpass, I use mip level 0 as shader input, mip level 1 as the render target.
For second subpass, I use mip level 1 as shader input, mip level 2 as the render target.

...

However, I got the validation error:
[image]

Is it possible that different subpasses use different mipmaps of same texture as render target? If it is possible, how can I implement it? Or I have to use the `VK_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_IMAGELESS_BIT` in validation error message.

Comment: "*The workflow is like the below screenshot:*" This workflow makes no sense. How do you start with "attachment 0" before a subpass can use it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, the frame buffer in screenshot is wrong. The frame buffer should not contain attachment 0. The mip level 0 of the texture is prepared in advance. I will correct the picture.

Answer (score 1):

No, all subpasses must have the same resolution (and practically, even if it was accepted there wouldn't be any benefit, as tilers would be unable to merge subpasses with different dimensions). Just use N render passes.